# Advanced MySQL Query (ranking results based on 2 other tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to make this work properly for a while now but just can't get my head around how to go about it, hopefully someone here can help me!

I have three tables:

```
Table A
Table B
Table C
```

I want to get the top 10 results from Table A based on a ranking that will depend on information from table B and table C. The ranking will be using the following formula:

```
Ranking = (COUNT(id) 
    from table C 
    WHERE c.a_id = a.id) as count_weight + 
    (COUNT(id) 
    FROM table B 
    WHERE b.a_id = a.id)*(count_weight*0.25) + a.views
```

In words I want the ranking to be equal to a point value determined by:

1. The count of records in Table C that correspond to the record in Table A that I'm interested in
2. If a record exists in Table B that corresponds to the record in Table A I'm interested in, I want an additional increase in the points by 25% (taking the points gained from #1 and multiply by 0.25) - In this case a record will exist or wont exist so it will always be 0 or 1
3. Points for each "view" for the record in Table A (a field of table A)

Hopefully I worded that in a understandable manner!

Thanks!

Comment: If possible try creating sql fiddle and make an example of output you'd like to achieve

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help make this more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(c.id) * IF(COUNT(b.id),1.25,1) + a.views AS Ranking
FROM a LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY Ranking DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If you don't want to select the Ranking, you can put that column's formula directly into the ORDER BY clause.